# How can I avoid unnecessary rerenders when storing complex state in Apollo reactive variables?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

Reactive variables make a lot of sense when storing simple, scalar values, but if you need to deal with more complex state (say, an `ID->object` map) you're going run into rendering performance issues.  The problem is that reactive variables are effectively immutable: you can't just mutate some sub-property of the variable and expect it to react correctly; you need to supply an entirely new value for the variable.  But then *every component* that is listening to that variable will rerender, even though many of them may not care about that particular property.

I'll clarify this with an example.  Say I have this reactive variable:

```js
const itemsMapVar = makeVar({
    item1: { text: "Text 1" },
    item2: { text: "Text 2" }
})
```

And I render a list of items, each of which looks like this:

```js
const ListItem = (props) => {
    const item = useReactiveVar(itemsMapVar)[props.id];
    return <div>{item.text}</div>
}
```

Suppose I modify the text for item 1:

```js
itemsMapVar({
    ...itemsMapVar(),
    item1: { text: 'New text' }
})
```

Now *both* item1 and item2 will rerender, because they're both listening to `itemsMapVar`.  That might not be a problem in this trivial example, but if there is a long list of DOM-heavy items, it will be a problem.  Is there an established best practice for dealing with this?

Some options I've considered:

- Use a different client state library.  Something like Redux or MobX solves this sort of problem easily.  One big downside is that I can't use that state as part of a reactive GraphQL query, which is probably why I'm using Apollo in the first place.
- Put a wrapper component around `<ListItem>` that contains the `useReactiveVar` hook and pulls out the property I'm interested in.  Then a `React.memo` on `ListItem` will prevent it from rendering unnecessarily.  This isn't terrible; but you still render O(N) items, but they're just lightweight wrapper items.  And it feels kind of verbose and clunky for what seems like a common problem when dealing with client state.
- Invent some new version of `useReactiveVar` that knows how to select out the part of the state that you need, akin to Redux's `useSelector`.  (Does such a thing already exist?)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to use multiple `makeVar` to avoid that.

for an example

```js
import { makeVar } from "@apollo/client";

const toggle = false;
const testing = true;

export const testingMutation = makeVar(testing);
export const toggleMutation = makeVar(toggle);
```

and then in your inMemoryCache read like as below

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          testingMutation: {
            read() {
              return testingMutation();
            },
          },
          toggleMutation: {
            read() {
              return toggleMutation();
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
```